# Are 'subdue' and 'attenuate' synonym?

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

The definitions of these two verbs on Cambridge Dictionary (online) mean more or less the same to me, exemplary sentences as well. However, 'thesaurus.com' doesn't show any connection between them. Are they synonyms, if not, what's the difference between them?

subdue(v): to reduce the force of something, or to prevent something from existing or developing [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/s%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk/ingilizce/subdue)

attenuate(v): to make something less or weaker [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/s%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk/ingilizce/attenuate)

Comment: I would say these are generally not synonyms, but would need to see examples of how you intend to use them. Context is everything. Can you please edit your question and include an example sentence where you think they may be synonymous?

Comment: @BillyKerr Hello, in the examples on the web pages that I referenced, I think they are interchangeable, so I believe that they should be synonyms though

Comment: Then the answer would have to be no. In most of the first set of examples, attenuate wouldn't work as a synonym.  Subduing something implies that some force is used against something, to actively suppress it.  In most instances attenuate just means to lessen/reduce something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not interchangeable. They seem close but have different influences.
The best I can think to differentiate is that one is a 'force', the other is a 'resistance'.

The police can subdue a rioter - ie forcibly detain or wrestle to the ground.
You can't subdue electricity to bring down the voltage - you attenuate it.

You can subdue a wild fire, but you attenuate the flame on your cooker, or the volume on your HiFi.